# Sympy solving simply PDE system

Tags: python, sympy

when solving a system of partial differential equation using [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) I'm facing a problem. A reduced problem looks as following:

My simplified problem consists of two PDEs

```
d           
──(u(x)) = 0
dx         

                        2      
d          d           d       
──(v(x)) = ──(u(x)) + ───(u(x))
dx         dx           2      
                      dx
```

the solution I expect is `d/dx(v(x))=0`. I want to solve this with sympy.

But when doing the following

```py
from sympy import *

u = Function('u',Real=True)(x)
v = Function('v',Real=True)(x)
eq1 = Eq(diff(u,x), 0)
eq2 = Eq(diff(v,x), diff(u,x,x)+diff(u,x))

solve([eq1,eq2],diff(v,x))
```

the output is

```
⎧                       2      ⎫
⎪d         d           d       ⎪
⎨──(v(x)): ──(u(x)) + ───(u(x))⎬
⎪dx        dx           2      ⎪
⎩                     dx       ⎭
```

which is identical with the one obtained by calling

```py
solve([eq2],diff(v,x))
```

Question: Why is the eq1 not inserted? At least in the first diff term which exactly matches the equation? How can I trigger this or I am doing something wrong here?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're solving PDEs but these are ODEs. Also you aren't really "solving" in the ordinary sense for differential equations but just trying to eliminate one variable from two equations.

You can just solve one equation and substitute into the other:

```
In [21]: eq1
Out[21]: 
d           
──(u(x)) = 0
dx          

In [22]: eq2
Out[22]: 
                        2      
d          d           d       
──(v(x)) = ──(u(x)) + ───(u(x))
dx         dx           2      
                      dx       

In [23]: [udsol] = solve(eq1, u.diff(x))

In [24]: udsol
Out[24]: 0

In [26]: eq2.subs(u.diff(x), udsol)
Out[26]: 
d          d    
──(v(x)) = ──(0)
dx         dx   

In [27]: eq2.subs(u.diff(x), udsol).doit()
Out[27]: 
d           
──(v(x)) = 0
dx
```

In general `solve` is for algebraic rather than differential equations.

Comment: The problem I intend to solve is a set of PDEs. Here, ODE is given for simplification. Giving sympy each step I could do by hand is clear. But doing this for a complicated system is not clear to me. Unfortunately, `dsolve` is only capable of handling one function, yet.

Comment: `dsolve` function can handle systems of ODEs but it's goal is to give explicit solutions for all functions so it won't give the output that you asked for (`v' = 0`).